# Calling a method from another class stops at that statement

Tags: java, methods, call

I do not really understand what is going on with my program. I call a method from [another class] and somehow [the class that called the method] stops working where the call was made and doesnt execute the rest of the program.

No errors popped up either, it simply just didnt run the rest (Checked with print statements)

Here is my code :

*Class that calls the method*

```
Banana ban = new Banana();
String[] listOfBananas = ban.getBananas(); //Stops at this statement
//Below is a check that never gets executed as with the rest of the program
System.out.println("I didnt get to this statement");

//Do other stuff with the array...
```

*Class that has the method*

```
public class Banana {
    public static String[] giveOtherClassList;

    public Banana(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        a.append("text text1 text2 text3");
        giveOtherClassList = a.toString().split(" "); //Split will create an array
    }

    public String[] getBananas() {
        //I know this method works because I ran this program with
        //giveOtherClassList[3] and it returned the correct value
        return giveOtherClassList;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may have `checked with print statements`... but have you actually `debugged`?

Comment: Could it be that you are executing the `main` method within `Banana` instead of the `main` method you actually want to execute? Furthermore, you have some syntax-errors `Bananas ban =...` -> `Banana ban = ...` and `giveOtherclassList` declared outside of a class)

Comment: giveOtherClassList array is declared outside of class Banana ?

Comment: oops that was a typo *edited*
the main method within Banana was just for testing purposes, I have another main method, but I will try making it a method instead to see if that helps

Comment: You need to show the entire class containing the procedure you're running.

Comment: i would say @Turing85 got it with wrong main method executed

Comment: @RyanJ OP edited question, it was outside

Comment: Hold on I will be posting more of the code to see if that helps. But its a lot because its 3 classes: One class that calls the first piece of code with a main method, a Second which uses the array, and the third which creates the array from a server.

Comment: `giveOtherClassList[] = a.toString().split(" "); //Split will create an array` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Brian just set up your test runs (aka. entry methods) properly or delete all unnecessary `main` methods. See my answer for a method to verify the correct `main` gets executed.

Comment: @RyanJ how is that a syntax error may I ask?

Comment: @Brian It appears you've changed your code to remove said error, so it's not relevant, but since you asked, assigning an array object to an array reference and leaving the [] causes an unexpected token compiler error.

Comment: @Brian the brackets (`[]`) were wrong. I removed them.

Comment: Nvm Turing fixed it for me which is why I was confused. Thanks @RyanJ for catching that and turing for fixing it

Comment: @Turing85 good edit, but you probably shouldn't edit syntax errors out of the post, since the OP may have them in their code and it paints an artificially wrong picture to the rest of the people helping to fix an error. Being that the OP had a working set of code, it was a non-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code you provided, I am pretty sure the `main` method within `Banana` gets executed instead of the code you actually want to execute. Just remove the `main` method within `Banana` and rerun the test. To be sure: add `System.out.println("Start");` as the first line within your `main`.

Here is a MWE just for documentation purpose:

```
public class Main implements Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Banana ban = new Banana();
        String[] listOfBananas = ban.getBananas();
        System.out.println("I didnt get to this statement");
    }
}

class Banana {
    public static String[] giveOtherClassList;

    public Banana() {
    }

    public String[] getBananas() {
        return giveOtherClassList;
    }
}
```

This program produces the output `I didnt get to this statement`, which - clearly - is not true and therefore the program works :)

Comment: I have 3 classes: One class that calls the first piece of code with a main method, a Second which uses the array, and the third which creates the array from a server. The main in Banana was to test the connection to the server and to make sure it was receiving the data to put into an array

Comment: The Creation of a new Banana and getting the list of bananas is actually in another method that is called from a Monkey class;
Therefore the main method is in the monkey class, however, your solution might work. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian that does not really matter. Your core-problem was the execution of a wrong `main` method.